# Plotting arbitrary Boolean Function using python Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm new to Plotly (just started today). Have created few heatmaps using it. Is it possible to plot arbitrary Boolean functions in Plotly ? For example i want Boolean function 0111 (OR Function) to be each of rectangle block where 0's and 1's have different color. Searched internet no idea how to start.

Comment: I mean rather than plotting each block by myself i could just take variable with that Boolean function as value and say something about distinct elements color. Thanks

Comment: Does this link solve your problem? https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-visualize-3-columns-with-boolean-values/36181/4